# query to update single row with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to run the following update script

```
update table1 set col1 = 'xxxx', 
col2 = (select cc.client_type
        from table2 t2, table3 t3, table1 t1
        where t2.col3='YYY' 
        AND t3.col4 != 'aaa'
        AND t3.col5 = 'Y'
)
```

I am getting following error

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

I am using Oracle 10g. **Any help on this??**

Comment: What must be in col2? What you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL error ORA 01427](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358188/sql-error-ora-01427)

Comment: how can you store multiple values in one column? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to update col2 that simply contains SOMETHING

Comment: @akhil what?, please, post an example of what you want, since *i want to update col2 that simply contains SOMETHING* doesn't make much sense

Comment: where is `cc.client_type` coming from there is no table with `cc` alias? If you need SOMETHING then why not add `rownum = 1` and store first value from subquery?

Comment: thanks for the help guys... I guess I am unable to explain my issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 t set col1='xxx',
col2= (select cc.client_type from table2 t2, table3 t3
where t2.col3='YYY' 
    AND t3.col4 != 'aaa'
    AND t3.col5 = 'Y'
    AND t2.random_col=t3.random_col)
```

will update necessary record (provided inner query returns only one row). However, it will be a constant value (where random_col is some column which can be associated with both table2 and table3, random_col2 is some column which can be associated with both table3 and table1)

Another possibility can be :-

```
update table1 t set col1='xxx',
    col2= (select cc.client_type from table2 t2, table3 t3
    where t2.col3='YYY' 
        AND t3.col4 != 'aaa'
        AND t3.col5 = 'Y'
        AND t2.random_col=t3.random_col
        AND t3.randome_col2=t.random_col2)
```

The above will update table1 with different(or same) values depending on table2 and table3

Comment: adding AND rownum=1 will update only the first row...

Comment: This returns a random row. What use is that?

Comment: @akhil, your requirement makes no sense

Comment: sorry. just edited the code

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because, as it states, the subquery is returning more than one row.  Your query is updating the entire table1 with the same data currently.  I'd suggest somehow joining to the outer table1 reference so that you get one row in the subquery for each row in the outer query.  Something like

```
update table1 t0 set col1 = 'xxxx', 
col2 = (select cc.client_type
    from table2 t2, table3 t3, table1 t1
    where t2.col3='YYY' 
    AND t3.col4 != 'aaa'
    AND t3.col5 = 'Y'
    AND t0.colx = t1.colx
)
```